# Skyrim Dragonborn DLC possible leveling bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

> Some of the following might contain spoilers regarding the main questline in the Dragonborn expansion.

In the Dragonborn expansion, there is an instance where one enters Hermaeus Mora's realm after reading the Black Book obtained in the dwermer ruins in Solstheim, and is commanded to read throughout his chapters. While doing this quest, I was level 61. When I finished all chapters, I met Hermaeus Mora and had a little chat, and it ended with me choosing one of the three Dragonborn flames. I choose that which enhances my Fus Ro Dah shout, and was then sent back to the ruins. After a chat with the conjurer, I noted I had level up, but all the way to level 81! Thus, I got 20 perks.

Is this a bug? Is this Mora's gift? On a side note, is it possible to obtain more perk points to spend?

Comment: Once you hit level 81, there are no more perk points (since you don't gain any more levels) for the regular skills.  If you have the Dawnguard DLC, there may still be perks to earn for your Vampire Lord or Werewolf skill tree.

Comment: I checked the Bugs section for this quest (I presume I'm looking at the right book?) on [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Black_Book:_Epistolary_Acumen_%28quest%29) and found no mention of this bug.  Doesn't mean it isn't known - just perhaps not well-known.  It's definitely *not* the way the quest is supposed to function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds very much like a bug. The Black Book in question is merely one of many, and all but one of them grant three choices, of which you pick one. Also, your main level should never, ever go up except via leveling skills, so if your skills weren't increased at the same time, it's 100% a bug. And unless you're made a skill Legendary (see below), 81 is the normal cap, so your skills would need to be basically all 100. Even if they've increased, though, it's basically guaranteed to be a bug.

As to your side note, yes, there is a way to get more perk points. [Skyrim patch 1.9 added the ability to make a skill that has reached 100 Legendary.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skills#Legendary_Skills) This resets the skill to its base level of 15, while also giving back the perk points that skill had (since many of those perks are ones you're no longer qualified for). Because the skill was reset, you can level it up to 100 again, gaining character levels as you go.

Additionally, if you're not willing to give up your skill levels for more perks, you can simply complete the main Dragonborn questline. The rewards at the end include an ability to reset the perks on a tree at a cost of one Dragon Soul. Your level in that skill remains as it was, but all the perks are refunded. It's not quite the same as gaining new perks, but it can be very useful for things like fixing mistakes, and also refunding perk points on crafting skills. You might not want to reset your Enchanting, in case you need it again, but you can reassign the perk points for a while. If you need your Enchanting perks again, a quick trip to Solstheim and a couple dragon souls is all it takes.